# StreamWriter has a Bug?

Tags: c#

this simply writes the text in textbox to the same file each time...I don't understand why it works perfectly if I input new characters or change characters while deleting characters doesn't work...

```
 private void ContentChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cur before:" + this.Box.SelectionStart);
            FileStream f = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(f);
            model.Cursor = this.Box.SelectionStart;
            writer.Write(this.Box.Text);
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("cur after:" + this.Box.SelectionStart);
            Console.WriteLine("write:" + count++);
            Console.WriteLine("after write:" + this.Box.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("after write:" + model.Content);
        }
```

Comment: By "doesn't work" I meant it didn't seem to write the new string to the file. it showed the correct content in the console though.

Comment: When you say delete doesn't work, have you tried deleting from both the start and the end of the text box? My guess is that you are deleting from the end and the text that was in the file previously does not get overwritten, but deleting from the beginning causes some characters to be left at the end of the file that are incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not closing `f` or flushing - it's entirely possible that the data is being buffered, which is why it never makes it to the file.

Two suggestions:

- Use `using` statements with disposable resources such as streams and writers
- Use [`File.CreateText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx) to create a `TextWriter` in one call - or better yet, use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) to avoid having to worry about opening and closing at all.

So something like this:

```
private void ContentChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("cur before:" + this.Box.SelectionStart);
    File.WriteAllText(path, this.Box.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("cur after:" + this.Box.SelectionStart);
    Console.WriteLine("write:" + count++);
    Console.WriteLine("after write:" + this.Box.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("after write:" + model.Content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it won't work for my case. My program requires that multiple threads have access to the same file at the same time, so File.WriteAllText won't work.

Comment: I also tried using and closing/disposing f...unfortunately, none worked

Comment: @user1447343: Given that you're opening and closing the file quickly, I would *strongly* advise you to stick to one thread accessing the file at a time, using locking. Aside from anything else, this may even be the cause of the problem you're having.

Comment: the point of this program is to allow people (multithread) to access the file and edit it at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** you need to re-write your code like in the following sample by `using` keyword. As it prevents the leaks and is recommended way to deal with un-managed resources in .NET Framework.

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream))
{
    writer.WriteLine("col1,col2,col3");
    writer.WriteLine("1,2,3");
    writer.Close(); //not necessary I think... end of using block should close writer
}
```

**Edit:** In your code sample you are opening the `FileStream` but do not close it, which causes the issues. Thus, preventing that with a convenient using statement is proffered way to go. Otherwise, you just need to close your filstream or any un-managed resources.

Comment: same problem...can't write a string shorter than what's there

Answer (score 0):

I found out why.

The StreamWriter constructor I used couldn't set the attribute "append" to false, so each time I'm overriding the existing text, not starting from scratch.

Since I have to use FileStream for multi-thread reason, I guess I would have to find another way of writing the file.

Comment: That wouldn't explain the description you gave of not writing the string to the file. It would write the string to the file, but just overwrite everything else. (You never *said* you were trying to append a value. This is a good example of how important it is to write a clear question.) Additionally, I'd still recommend that you try to avoid writing from multiple threads at the same time. Either synchronize access, or have *one* thread whose sole job is to write to this file, and which gets data from a producer/consumer collection that other threads add to.